# Keep link box the same size even with different text

Tags: html

When making a menu I have my hover effects on my ancor links. I pad these to change their size as height/width doesn't work. The issue now is due to the padding the boxes are different widths due to the different length text in them. How can I  make my ancor links all the same size?

Comment: Why is height/width not working?

Comment: float your anchors or display block